# Mypy compliant type hints of class attributes similar to SQAlchemy's ORM

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to get typing working similar how SQAlchemy's ORM model declaration works:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class MyClass(Base):
    name = Column(String(30))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name.zfill(3)}"
```

In this example you can see how `name` is declared as a `Column(String(30))`, but when the class is initialized, name can be used as `self.name` and will be a string. The part I'm most interested about is having mypy not throw any errors and an IDE recognize this and help with formatting, in this case  [PyCharm correctly assumes `name` is a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H66M9.png)

I've been checking out their source code but I can't understand how they're making it work. As a very brief example, this would be ideally how types are defined:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional, Type


class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, attr_type: Optional[Type[Any]] = None):
        self.attr_type = attr_type


class MyModel(object):
    # This would be nice
    name: str = Attribute()
    # But this could work too
    name2 = Attribute(str)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name.zfill(3)}"
```

Although at the moment this small snippet makes mypy complain:

```
type_checker_test.py:11: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Attribute", variable has type "str")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: In the statement  name: str = Attribute() you are attempting to assign a left side of type str with a right side which is an instance of class Attribute. An instnace of a class doesn't have a type of str. This is what Mypy flags as an incompatible assignment. I'm not sure that completely answers your question

Comment: @paisanco Thanks for the answer. I haven't included here the inner workings of the class to make it simple, but be it via metaclass or `__new__` the attributes on the class instance will be accessible as they are on the sqlalchemy model, so while the class's attributes are of type `Attribute` the instance's attributes will be of the hinted type.

Comment: Like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=c05726e5d9af03b1e4a9851360607d25) (gist mine)? If you don't use descriptors in fact, you can use it as a stub or within `if TYPE_CHECKING` block (because descriptors are well-supported and metaclasses are not)